# What is the `context` parameter that is passed to the callback functions

Tags: javascript, goinstant

I see a lot of callback functions accept a parameter referred to as `context` in the GoInstant documentation, but it's not clear what this parameter is or what it's used for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The context parameter contains meta-data about the event.

The full docs are here: https://developers.goinstant.net/v1/key/context.html

It includes:

- the type of command (SET, GET, etc.)
- the name of the key
- the value of the key *after* the operation
- the room to which the key belongs
- the user that instantiated the action
- a `local` boolean used to indicate whether the change was triggered locally or remotely
- and a bubble boolean used to indicate whether the event was triggered from this key or a child key.

It can be useful to understand where and why you are receiving the event.

Disclosure: I work at GoInstant.

Comment: That is pretty bad name for a parameter of a function that takes a callback